# TFS reconcile after gated check-in validation deletes all [merge, branch] changes in my local workspace

Tags: tfs, merge, gated-checkin

Every time I check-in changes to the gated build that includes new files via a branch merge, when I reconcile, the new files are deleted from my workspace and I have to do a get latest **with override** to re-obtain the files. This does not affect simple [add] changes however.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This has been happening for years, even after upgrading from VS 2010, thru 2013 and 2015 to 2017. I have even received a completely new workstation since the bug began.

Thanks.

TFS 2015 (version 14.102.25423.0)

Visual Studio version seems irrelevant, but currently I am on 2017 Professional (version 15.9.16)

Answer (score -1):

Seems you cleared the option `Preserve my pending changes locally` in the Gated Check-in dialog box when build changes.

To preserve the changes or new files you need to keep the option **selected**.

Please see [Check in to a folder that is controlled by a gated check-in build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/check-folder-controlled-by-gated-check-build-process?view=vsts) for details.

- [Proceed with the gated check-in after keeping the changes in your
  workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/check-folder-controlled-by-gated-check-build-process?view=vsts#proceed-with-the-gated-check-in-after-keeping-the-changes-in-your-workspace)
- [Proceed with the gated check-in after deleting the changes in your
  workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/check-folder-controlled-by-gated-check-build-process?view=vsts#proceed-with-the-gated-check-in-after-deleting-the-changes-in-your-workspace)

[image]

Comment: @Elaskanator Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No, I have the option enabled to preserve my local changes. And the issue only occurs when I am merging ADD changes between branches (when I do the check in to the originating branch the ADD change is reconciled properly).